# Modify string names in a data frame based on a condition

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I have a data frame with a variable called "Control_Category". The variable has six names in it, which for simplicity sake I am going to make generic:

```
df <- data.frame(Control_Category = c("Really Long Name One",
"Super Really Long Name Two",
"Another Really Flippin' Long Name Three",
",Seriously, It's a Fourth Long Name",
"Definitely a Fifth Long Name",
"Finally, This guy is done, number six"))
```

I'm using this to make a slight joke. So, while the names are long they are  tidy in that the values for each (1-6) are consistent. In this specific character vector of the data.frame, there are hundreds and hundreds of entries that match any one of those six.

What I need to do is to replace the long names with a short name. Therefore, where any of the above names are identified, replace that name with a shorter version, like:

One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six

I tried a function using 'case_when' and it failed miserably. Any help would be appreciated.

**Additional Information Based on Questions From Community**

The order of the items doesn't matter. There isn't a designation of 1 - 6. There just happen to be six and I made six stupid long strings. The strings themselves are long.

So, anywhere "Super Really Long Name Two" exists, that value needs to be updated to something like 'TWO" or a "Short_Name" that that approximate "TWO". In reality, the category is called "Audit, Testing and Examination Results". The short name would ideally just be "AUDIT".

Comment: In your real data, are 4 and 5 always represented by "fourth", "fifth", in contrast to 1, 2, 3 and 6 which are always "one", "two", "three", "six" ?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is factor: `df$Control_Category <- factor(df$Control_Category, levels=df$Control_Category, labels=c(1:6))`

Comment: @parksw3 I think in the real data, there are more than 6 rows and the values to replace are not ordered.

Comment: @neilfws Yes, but if he knows what the names are and how he wants them to be ordered, he can specify the levels and labels appropriately. Let me try to write a longer answer below ...

Comment: I know `factor`s aren't cool any more, but this is a perfect application for them.

Comment: Order doesn't matter. It's just that there happen to be six categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use `gsub()` once for each replacement:

```
df$Control_Category <- gsub('Really Long Name One', 'One',  df$Control_Category)
```

You can repeat similar logic to handle the other five long/short name pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a larger data frame with long names:

```
set.seed(101)
long_names <- c("Really Long Name One",
                "Super Really Long Name Two",
                "Another Really Flippin' Long Name Three",
                ",Seriously, It's a Fourth Long Name",
                "Definitely a Fifth Long Name",
                "Finally, This guy is done, number six")

df <- data.frame(control_category=sample(long_names, 100, replace=TRUE))
head(df)

##                          control_category
## 1 Another Really Flippin' Long Name Three
## 2                    Really Long Name One
## 3            Definitely a Fifth Long Name
## 4     ,Seriously, It's a Fourth Long Name
## 5              Super Really Long Name Two
## 6              Super Really Long Name Two
```

Using the `unique` function will give you the category names:

```
category <- unique(df$control_category)
print(category)

## [1] Another Really Flippin' Long Name Three
## [2] Really Long Name One                   
## [3] Definitely a Fifth Long Name           
## [4] ,Seriously, It's a Fourth Long Name    
## [5] Super Really Long Name Two             
## [6] Finally, This guy is done, number six  
## 6 Levels: ,Seriously, It's a Fourth Long Name ...
```

Notice that the levels are in alphabetical order (see `levels(category)`). In this case, the simplest way is to change the order manually by looking at the current order. In this case, `category[c(2, 5, 1, 4, 3, 6)]` will give you the right order. Finally,

```
df$control_category <- factor(
    df$control_category,
    levels=category[c(2, 5, 1, 4, 3, 6)],
    labels=c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")
)
head(df)

##   control_category
## 1            three
## 2              one
## 3             five
## 4             four
## 5              two
## 6              two
```

Comment: Order doesn't matter. I just need to replace all of the names as specified above in the updated question. I.e., loop through that column of data, evaluate the name, update it, move on, repeat.